# Listen to guitar using audio interface

Tags: audio, audio-interfaces, guitar

I plug my Alesis Core 1 via usb into my PC. It appears as a recording device, if I right click on that and go into advanced and then click "Listen to this device", although I can hear my guitar there is latency of around half a second.

I read through the website and it said to install asio4all, I did, I set it up but I cannot hear the guitar still.

I'm not using any software, just asio4all. I've tried googling a thousand times and I do not know the correct phrase to google no doubt because I can't find a single thread anywhere on how to just listen to the guitar.

I don't want to record the device, I only want to listen to the device lag free.

How do I go about doing this? I've tried guitar rig but it doesn't allow any other audio other than itself and even then I couldn't hear the guitar.

I tried audacity but I can only hear the guitar when recording, it might seem pointless to ask but why do I have to record just to listen to the guitar?

Ok, update, I was thinking how stupid it is to ask this question and decided to just use audacity, record to listen, then delete the track but now there is about 100-200ms of latency with my audio playback.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the device has no direct routing (internally) from its input to its output. 
The signal goes through an input DAC making it digital, which the device then sends to the computer. Communicating with the PC takes skill and a different way of processing than bringing it straight out. If it is not built with that way of processing, there is no setting that says "bypass PC" or something alike. 
It sounds though as if you're only looking for a small amplifier from guitar level to line level, and you can pick up a cheap second hand one (e.g. a Danelectro Honey-something perhaps) to do that.

Comment: I think this is what I was expecting when I bought the device. The only way I'm able to get it to work is to read the input from the core 1 over usb, have the signal processed on my pc and sent to the phones jack on the core 1, then use a jack to the line in on my pc and directly play that sound through the windows sound mixer. All of this using Cubase

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have sound using a core 1 then download a free daw (eg audacity) and just run the guitar through that. The core 1 should however come with cubase LE (or at least it did when I bought mine) which is perfect for both recording and just playing through with lots of the built in effects of cubase. If it did come with cubase LE then download that onto your computer and run the guitar through that.

Comment: I've managed to get a signal using cubase LE but for reasons I can't send the signal straight to my sound card, it has to be sent to the phones jack on the core 1, then using a line in on my PC I have to listen to the device.